# Heroku Rails Rake Task to Sync Production & Local DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm trying to create a rake task so that I can simply type "rake db:sync" in order to update my local DB to match production.

This solution leverages code provided by the Heroku team here:
[Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

When I use curl --output /tmp/latest.dump #{url} I'm getting the following error in my latest.dump file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code><Message>Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and X-Amz-Expires parameters.</Message><RequestId>421FEFF763870123</RequestId><HostId>vlVr/ihmQiDgYIpdFFkuCgEP8Smvr2ks0wRkf89fJ8NfHfsBb92EVv40Q0NZuQIC</HostId></Error>
```

Here is the code I'm using.

```
    #lib/tasks/db_sync.rake
     namespace :db do
      desc 'Pull production db to development'
      task :sync => [:backup, :dump, :restore]

      task :backup do
        Bundler.with_clean_env { 
          puts 'Backup started...'
          system "heroku pg:backups capture --app YOUR_APP_NAME"
          puts 'Backup complete!'
        }
      end

      task :dump do
        dumpfile = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/latest.dump"
        puts 'Fetching url and file...'
        Bundler.with_clean_env { 
          url = `heroku pg:backups public-url --app YOUR_APP_NAME | cat` 
          system "curl --output #{dumpfile} #{url}"
        }
        puts 'Fetching complete!'
      end

      task :restore do
        dev = Rails.application.config.database_configuration['development']
        dumpfile = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/latest.dump"
        puts 'PG_RESTORE on development database...'
        system "pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U #{dev['username']} -d #{dev['database']} #{dumpfile}"
        puts 'PG_RESTORE Complete!'
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Parity gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/parity). It offers several commands to do the following Heroku Rails tasks easily -

1. Backup DB's
2. Restore DB's
3. Run `rails console`
4. Tail logs
5. Run migrations
6. Deploy

You're of course primarily looking for the first two.

After installation, it expects that you have two `git remote` values set named `staging` and `production`. `development` isn't needed as it is assumed to be your local machine.

You can get the git url for the other two environments from your Heroku dashboard -> (your app) -> Settings -> Info

After you have that set up, it's as simple as

```
production backup
development restore production
```

The code is pretty simple, so I encourage you to read it. But it's essentially doing exactly what your rake code attempts to do by getting a public URL and restoring it.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. It's good practice for me to learn how to setup a staging environment in heroku, looks easier than I expected. I would still like to see a "rake" solution to this simple problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Although the solution did require me to setup a staging environment.

Comment: So if you follow the code, it jumps between a few classes and a few files, but the heart of it basically just pieces together two commands for the restore - (1) finding the public URL and (2) restoring it to whatever environment. You could piece those together and stick them into a rake task, although a gem is a convenient package so not sure the advantage of that approach. Best of luck!